# Publish .Net/SQL website on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, web

I have created a data-driven website using ASP.net and SQL Server 2014 express.
Everything is working correctly on IIS. I originally planned to host it on one of these hosts http://www.asp.net/hosting/home
but I think I want to host on Microsoft Azure. I don't know much about Azure. 
Can I easily convert the SQL database into Azure-compatible form? or do I just upload the SQL database on the Azure? Is there any tutorial I can follow for this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish direct from any modern version of Visual Studio. You may need to install the [Azure tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee405484.aspx) if they weren't initially. Right click on your project and hit publish, it'll walk you through a wizard and generate a powershell publish script for you.

SQL server is baked in to Azure as is, the publish wizard will give you the option to spin up an instance and automatically update your connection strings in your web.config.

From what I remember, I believe you will however need to execute your schema manually on the azure instance, or migrate the database directly.

There are certain operations azure does *not* support for SQL server (BULK INSERT comes to mind? - This may have been updated though), but it should operate pretty much the same as your local express instance.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean Publish Web App button after you right click the project. Then I see MS Azure Web App button.

Comment: So I published it but Internet Explorer cannot access the database. This is one of the publish setting which was automatically set when I created new web app.  (name).scm.azurewebsites.net:443 What did I do wrong? Do I need to upload my database mdf file?